# Is a mode or median more likely to be influenced by an outlier?

Tags: statistics

I just took a stats quiz and was asked

```
 Is a mode or median more likely to be influenced by an outlier?
```

I was marked incorrect by picking the median. Is this true? I feel like this question without a given dataset is very subjective.

Comment: Was "neither" an option?

Comment: alas, It was not

Comment: how are they defined in your class or at least in the notes that you're using?

Comment: Perhaps they were thinking of the question of if the *amount* that a mode can change by including or not an additional outlier greater than or less than the *amount* that a median can change.  A mode could feasibly change from being equal to the largest data point to the smallest while median can only shift one datapoint over.  That being said, the way the question is phrased it *reads* as being which occurs more *frequently*, a mode changing *at all* by including an outlier or the median changing, to which I would agree that the median ought to be more likely to change.

Answer (score 0):

An outlier is a data point that is far from all other data points.  So the only way it can change a mode is if all data points are unique, i.e. they are all in a tie for mode (in such a scenario it's silly to even talk about the mode).

On the other hand, if you have all distinct data points, the outlier will change the median depending on what side of the other data it is on. And it might change the median even if the data points are not all distinct.  So I would say that the median is more likely to be changed.